# AJAX code doesnt working with Django project

Tags: python, django, ajax

enter code hereIm making sort of a game where users can create or join a room with code and play a game...For now i only want to show all the users that are in the one room and i dont want the page to refresh when someone new enters. I asked few guys on reddit and they said i should use AJAX so i watched some tutorials but it doesn show anything.

here is my code:

````py
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from hashlib import new
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Room, User
from django.contrib import messages
from random import randint
from django.http import JsonResponse

def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

def index(request): 
    return render(request, 'index.html')
def checkroom(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Uspeo = False
        username = ''
        code = 0
        # join with code
        if 'dugme1' in request.POST:
            username = request.POST["username"]
            no1 = request.POST["no1"]
            no2 = request.POST["no2"]
            no3 = request.POST["no3"]
            no4 = request.POST["no4"]
            no5 = request.POST["no5"]
            no6 = request.POST["no6"]
            number = no1+no2+no3+no4+no5+no6
            
            if len(username) == 0:
                messages.info(request, 'Enter your name!')
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                if Room.objects.filter(Room_code=number).exists():
                    user = User.objects.create(username=username, code=number)
                    user.save()
                    return redirect('/room/?code=' + number + '&username=' + username)
                else:
                    messages.info(request, 'Code not found!')
                    return redirect('/')
        #make room
        elif 'dugme' in request.POST:
            code = random_with_N_digits(6)
            while Uspeo != True:
                if Room.objects.filter(Room_code=code).exists():
                    Uspeo = False
                    code = random_with_N_digits(6)
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    Uspeo = True
                    new_code = Room.objects.create(Room_code = code)
                    new_code.save()
                    return redirect('/makeroom/?code=' + str(code))
        else: pass
def makeroom(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    formatted_code = code[:3] + " " + code[3:]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username2']
        user = User.objects.create(username=username, code=code)
        user.save()
        return redirect("/room/?code="+code+"&username="+ username)
    return render(request, "makeroom.html",{'code':formatted_code})
def room(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    username = request.GET.get("username")
    #users = User.objects.filter(code=code)
    return render(request, "room.html")     
def get_users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        users = User.objects.filter(code=code)
        user_list = [{'username': user['username']} for user in users]
        return JsonResponse(user_list, safe=False)```
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Make Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Users in Room</h1>
    <ul id="display">
        {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function refreshUsers() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/get_users/', // Replace with your Django view URL that returns the list of users
                data: {'code': '{{ code }}'}, // Pass the room code as a parameter to the view
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#display').empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $('#display').append('<li>' + data[i].username + '</li>');
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(refreshUsers, 5000); // Refresh the list of users every 5 seconds
    </script>
</body>
</html>`

you can check out video where i demonstrate how my project work on reddit: [link ][1]

I tried asking ChatGPT and watching tutorials but nothing works. I expect to show all the users in one room but it shows nothin(there is no errors)


  [1]: https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/11382fb/i_need_help/
````

Comment: you cant refresh your page with fresh data triggered by another user even with Ajax. It's a WebSocket concept. The same one we use in chat when someone sends you a message you get without refreshing the page and it won't work just only with Ajax.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: tbh I never used that. So not aware of the actual implementation. but search on youtube `tic tac toe game with django using websockets` that's the concept you're looking for.